# how to create a video gallery using video lightbox in magento

Tags: video, magento, lightbox

I am a newbie to website development using Magento. I wanted to know how we can use a video lightbox with Magento to create a video gallery.

I wanted the gallery to appear on a category page, and play the video in a pop-up on click of any thumbnail.

Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

Please have a look at this question. I am in urgent need of this answer. I will be highly grateful to you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [play video in separate pop-up sized window on product click in magento](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138572/play-video-in-separate-pop-up-sized-window-on-product-click-in-magento)

Comment: @clockworkgeek: Since there no responses to this question "play video in separate pop-up sized window on product click in magento". So it has been asked in a different manner.

Comment: It's only been a few hours and it's still early on a Monday morning, most of this site's visitors aren't out of bed yet. Both your questions are still on the first page of results for it's tag. I would try a little more patience. My above comment was automatically generated when I asked for moderators to consider merging the two questions. (And if you want to draw attention to an earlier post you can edit it to make it jump to the top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention that you're new to Magento development, so I would suggestion

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/TemplatesMaster/extension/1487/magento-easy-lightbox

Comment: Can we create video gallery using this extension. When I watched the live demo it shows only images.

Comment: This answer is wrong as using the suggested extension we can create only photo gallery but not video gallery.

Comment: you're kidding right? I'm using it! with video http://balexandre.com/temp/cattier_dk_004.png I changed the code a bit and this is the result I use

Comment: I would be highly grateful to you if you tell me what code modifications you did to work the video with it. I had been stuck with this issue for the last one week. Please help me.

Comment: Upvoting because balexandre's linked plugin seems to have what is necessary to get a lightbox going. Kiara, please try to work with this plugin and modify your code, as there doesn't appear to be a pre-packaged solution for exactly what you need.